# Partial in Clojure takes more than one function

Tags: clojure

I am trying to really understand partial in Clojure.  `partial` takes a function f and fewer than the normal arguments to f, and returns a fn that takes a variable number of additional args. When called, the returned function calls f with args + additional args.  This is the working example for partial seems not making sense to me `((partial map *) [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])`.  `map` and `*` are functions; therefore `partial` is taking more than one function and invalidating the definition.  Anyone can help me understand better?

Comment: map is a function that takes a function as its first argument

Comment: Ada, to amplify noisesmiths' comment and Chris Murphy's answer, the point is that in Clojure, functions are things just like numbers, strings, vectors, etc.  So "argument" in the description of `partial` can refer to arguments that are functions.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with a function being an argument. In your case `map *` is created, which can be used later:

```
(def will-map-multiply (partial map *))
```

As with any partial function the rest of its arguments can be supplied later:

```
(will-map-multiply [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9]) ;=> (28 80 162)
```

That was 'partialising' one of the arguments. It could have been two:

```
(def will-map-multiply-again (partial map * [1 2 3]))
(will-map-multiply-again [4 5 6] [7 8 9]) ;=> (28 80 162)
```

When using `partial` the first parameter must be a function, and the others can be whatever - no reason they can't also be functions.

Your example is a bit complex because multiplying *requires* two or more arguments, and hence `map` needs two or more sequences.

Comment: `*` does *not* require two or more arguments. It can be called with any (nonnegative integer of course) number of arguments.

Comment: `(*)` returns     `0`

Comment: @noisesmith No, `(*)` returns 1.

Comment: Interesting - calling an operator that's a monoid (with numbers) returns the identity element, which is 1 for * and 0 for +. Try `(/)`!

Comment: @ChrisMurphy `-` and `/` don't have identity values. They're not like `+` or `*`; they're basically just shortcuts, and they're not commutative or associative.

Comment: Yes. `/` is not a monoid with numbers so `(/)` crashes!

Comment: @ChrisMurphy You added emphasis to the word "requires" in your answer and tagged the change as "less confusing", but now I'm more confused than ever. In what way does `*` require two or more arguments?

Comment: Only in the way that it is kind of silly to multiply one number. In everyday common language multiplication requires two numbers. In Clojure you can stretch it to be more than one. Also it seems you can stretch it to be only one. Italics means 'this word is not all it seems'. Readers can find out what the excitement is all about in the comments. I wanted to keep the answer concise, and not complicated by edge case consideration.

Answer (score 1):

You're over-thinking it. The first argument to `partial` must be a function. The next arguments must be whatever would be valid arguments to that function you just named as the first argument -- including other functions, if your first parameter is a higher-order function like `map` or `reduce` or many others.

`(partial map *)`

The first argument is a function, `map`. The next argument is whatever would be a valid argument to `map`. Since `map` requires a function as its first argument, this `partial` expression requires a function as its second argument.

As simple as that. You can think of the `*` as an argument to the `map` first, and by extension, an argument to `partial`.

Answer (score 1):

Functions are first-class values in Clojure. This means, you can pass them around like, for example, integers, maps or strings.

So, there’s nothing strange with `(partial map *)`, where function `*` is just a `map`’s first argument. In your case, `partial` constructs a function which then passes additional collections to `map`. Let's see:

```clj
(partial map *)

;; becomes

(fn [coll1 coll2 coll3] ;; other arities ommited
  (map * coll1 coll2 coll3))

;; let’s call this fn with your collections

((fn [coll1 coll2 coll3]
 (map * coll1 coll2 coll3)) [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])

;; becomes

(map * coll1 coll2 coll3)
```

Again, the main point is that functions are first-class in Clojure and many other functional languages.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

`(partial map *)` looks strange, but when one realizes that map takes a **function** as its first argument, it becomes more clear. `*` is just a function that takes variable number of arguments and multiplies them. Therefore, 
`(map * [1 2 3] [4 5 6] [7 8 9])` applies `*` to three triples of numbers and produces `[28 80 162]`. All this has nothing to do with partial. The confusion stems from the fact that in clojure functions are often passed as **arguments** to other functions (actually this is becoming common in all modern languages, even JavaScript!).

So, `(partial map *)` means exactly: take `map` with pre-selected first argument (`*`) and create a new function that uses its arguments as vectors to perform the mapping.

Comment: Thank you for your question everyone!  They are great explanations!  I agreed i was over-thinking.  With clojure syntax is so clean and concise but didn't jump out to me at first.